# Is this the same droid in two scenes from the Force Awakens?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, character-identification

In this scene, we see...

> R2-D2 waving goodbye to Rey and Chewie in the Falcon 
>  [image]

But, here, in this next scene we see...

> That R2 is there with Chewie in the Island
>   [image]

**So, is it a big mistake in the movie??**

Comment: Still haven't seen TFA, but I think it's possible that the first picture shows **an** R2 unit, whereas the second picture shows **the** R2 unit - i.e., the first picture is some other R2 droid, and the second one is the R2 droid we  know and love.

Comment: Looking closely at the first photo, I'm pretty sure that is a different astromech droid, not R2-D2.

Comment: in terms of mistakes would this really be that huge?

Comment: would that be R2-KT?

Comment: The prequels gave R2D2 the ability to fly. The Sequels give him a hyperdrive. It's all part of the plan...

Comment: http://e.lvme.me/jws31z5.jpg

Comment: I'm pretty sure R2 would be next to C-3PO, both in-universe and from a filmmaking standpoint

Comment: The droid in the top picture is dark grey/white/blue whereas _the_ R2-D2 is white/blue. They are different droids. Source: walked out of the cinema about 3 hours ago.

Comment: This is minor oversight at best… Also, it's not like astromech droids weren't mass-produced or anything. Every X-Wing needed droid like that and they could've easily had few silver-blue R2 units around.

Comment: @AlessandroSanfilippo R2-KT is in that scene but not in that image; she's all pink and that R2 is blue. (She's off the right side of the screen in that shot, just barely getting on-camera)

Comment: Also, this picture doesn't really show it, but did C-3PO get his arm fixed and made gold again?  I swear I saw C-3PO with two gold arms in this exact shot when the Falcon is taking off.  Anyone have another pic of it?

Comment: The droid in the first image is **not the droid you are looking for.** (*I'll just see myself out...*)

Comment: I watched the film again this afternoon and the droid is indeed grey and blue, not white and blue. Also, yes, there are oodles of R2 and other Astromech units all over the place on the base, in all colours. I caught even the pink one, twice. Wasn't looking at C-3PO in that particular shot though.

Comment: Just saw the movie, and I was watching for this scene.  The droid in the first picture is definitely NOT R2-D2, but it definitely IS very similar, except for the coloring and shininess.  The droid is probably the same model as R2, but slightly newer (and exceedingly shiny), but the colors are different - no white, just silver and either dark blue or purple, or maybe even black.

Answer (score 27):

According to the novelization, R2-D2 was indeed with Chewbacca aboard the Falcon, so the first scene must have had some OTHER R2 astromech.

> Each time, Chewbacca would wave. Had he been equipped to do so, R2-D2 would have done likewise.
>   -  [From the novelization]

Answer (score 17):

I could be wrong but I believe the character in the top image is shinier, newer (i.e. different) than the one in the bottom image.

During the film, I recall thinking that the character in the top image looked familiar, but couldn't be who you (and I) thought it was. So the next image made sense to me. I had the thought "Oh okay, must have been a different character."

Comment: The Falcon might be dusty!

Comment: Calling the Falcon "dusty" is generous.

Answer (score 8):

Consider the placement of the individuals in the sending off scene. Front and center are C-3PO and BB-8.  Off to the side (and behind another person) is an R2 unit.

One would expect, that if that was R2-D2, he would have been standing in close proximity to the two droids in the middle given R2-D2's importance. That this expectation is not met indicates thats not R2-D2.

Comment: Yes, that sounds about right

Answer (score 7):

No, they are patently not the same droids. As you can see, the one that leaves the Falcon (pictured to the right below) has a blue top and white legs. Presumably it's R2-D2.

The one on the flight apron (pictured to the left) has a grey top and a grey body with a white trim.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

To me the droid looks more like R2-Q2 who was also in the Force Awakens action figure set.

[image]

Comment: It's *possible* that that droid is [R2-Q2](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/R2-Q2_(Imperial)) since he was last seen in the employ of the Empire in Star Wars: A New Hope. That being said, it's easily as likely (in fact far more likely) that it's another droid that happens to be the same colour...

Comment: If it's not R2-Q2, then it's another droid that looks *exactly* like him. Seems like a reasonable inference.

Comment: @DCShannon - Well, the last time we saw that particular droid, it was on board the [Devastator](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Devastator) which we now know was destroyed shortly after the Death Star II. Is it more likely that it's the same droid (complete with an amazing backstory about how it escaped being blown up with its ship and how it joined the Rebellion) or that it's just another droid with a similar paint-job?

Comment: @Richard I don't know. This is Star Wars after all. That being said, if the droid was destroyed on the Devestator, then why is it in the Force Awakens action figure set?

Comment: @DCShannon - I'm struggling to find it in any updated action sets. The latest I've been able to see was a [Disneyland pack](http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0865/6500/products/51-Fp0nsbWL_grande.jpg?v=1444001303) from 2009. The image above is actually a CGI rendering from [2008](http://astromech.net/gallery2/main.php?g2_itemId=13464).

Comment: @Richard Thomas's claim that it's in the action figure set is a big part of me upvoting this, so if that's not true then that's pretty relevant.